# How to verify that a physical volume is encrypted? (Ubuntu 10.04 w/ LUKS)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, encryption, disk-volume, luks

I am very new to LUKS.

During installation, I tried to set up an encrypted physical volume so that everything underneath it would be encrypted. I chose "Use as: physical volume for encryption," the installation completed and I have a working environment.

How can I verify that the PV is indeed encrypted?

I was never prompted to provide a passphrase, so I most likely missed a step somewhere. At the end of the day, I'd like whole disk encryption if that's possible, so I don't have to worry about which parts of the file system are encrypted and which aren't.

If I did miss something, do I have to start over and try again, or can it be done (relatively easily?) after the fact? I would prefer not to introduce more complexity by using TrueCrypt, etc.

Environment details:
The drives are md raid1. One volume group. A standard boot lv. An encrypted swap lv using a random key (which seems to be working fine).

Thank you in advance for your help. This is very much a learn-as-I-go experience.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for superuser.com.

Comment: In this case, it's ubuntu server, not desktop. Not sure if that changes anything?

Comment: The FAQ ( http://serverfault.com/faq ) should make it clear for you. It doesn't seem to me like you're doing this in a professional capacity, but that's from interpreting your post so I could be wrong.

Comment: This [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1205372) may be of some help.

Comment: @JMeterX - That clarifies things quite a bit, thank you! It seems Step 6, sub-step 2 didn't happen for me. Probably human error. 
gparent - professional, yes. An OJT exercise though. (so not in production ...yet.) Anyway, thank you both for your responses. I think JmeterX's link addresses my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in the comments the following link will help you with your understanding:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1205372

Comment: Can you add the relevant info here?